# How do I get the path from a Readable stream in Node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, testing

How do you find the path from a readable stream? This is an S3 PutObjectCommandInput from a test case (aws_sdk_client_mock) which returns a readable stream.

```
const putCall = s3Mock.call(1).args[0].input as PutObjectCommandInput
const readable = putCall.Body as Readable
const path = readable ???
```

I can see the path when debugging, but cannot find an API for it

```
    "Body": {
        "fd": null,
        "path": "/tmp/JbHO.csv",
```